# Engine.Razor throwing exception with same keys used more then once

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm trying to generate a template for emails in C# using the Engine.Razor lib from [here](https://github.com/Antaris/RazorEngine). But I don't understand what they key property is for?
According to the docs I run it like this

```
emailBody = Engine.Razor.RunCompile(emailBodyText, "SomeKey", null, new { SomeVariable = 3 });
```

And it generates some cached key called "SomeKey"! I don't really need this! But it's required in the parameters.

But the problem I have is that after I generate more then one email I get an exception saying the key has already been generated. So do I throw in a unique value every time I generate an email or am I missing something here about this library's use?

The older documentation says to use .Parse (no key needed) but Visual Studio shows it as deprecated!

```
string result = Razor.Parse(template, new { Name = "World" });
```

So I'm afraid to use this method even though it works!

Answer (score 1):

You did not continue reading the rest of the documentation on how to use this library or misinterpreted the `RunCompile` and `Run` sections.  From the author's website you linked, the steps are as follows.

```
string template = "Hello @Model.Name, welcome to RazorEngine!";
var result =
    Engine.Razor.RunCompile(template, "templateKey", null, new { Name = "World" });
```

> The RunCompile method used here is an extension method and you need to
>   open the RazorEngine.Templating namespace.
>
> The "templateKey" must be unique and after running the above example
>   you can **re-run the cached template with this key.**

```
// using RazorEngine.Templating; // Dont forget to include this.
var result =
    Engine.Razor.Run("templateKey", null, new { Name = "Max" });
```

Note, the next time the author runs the template with a new model value, he is calling `Engine.Razor.Run`.  If you were to call `RunCompile` again, you would need yet another unique key.

Comment: this is really confusing! Every time I generate an email template it will be different then the one before. ex. my user logged in might generate an email, send it, then 30 seconds later generate another email. This email will have different model info so I'll need a new template. So if I understand your answer I  need to use a unique identifier in the templateKey name everytime I use RunCompile? ex. "templateKey"+DateTime.Now.ToString()

Comment: it just seems a little wasteful to cache all these templates!

Comment: @user1186050 - no, you are reading it incorrectly.  Think about it this way.  You have a new user email template that takes a model of string (call it name).  You call the first item, `RunCompile` with a unique identifier and a model value (lets say Tommy).  Now, the next time you have to use *that specific email template*, you call the second command `.Run` with a *different model value* (lets say user1).  You call `RunCompile` once and only once for each of your templates.  From then on out, you call `Run` with a different model value on the unique template id.

Comment: @user1186050 - this is because the template is now cached and can be reused.  Notice from the documentation that they used two different `Name` parameters.

Comment: so I have to generate these templates either on startup or something. If I have a ASp MVC app where my controller is calling a service and that service runs some logic then needs to generate an email, the first time I start up the site I run the template then use that template after that??? That doesn't seem like good practice? HOw would you do this?

Comment: oh I think I see how to do it! there is a IsTemplateCached method. I guess you check if its generated then run it if it's not??